# Using an ag-grid inside an md-tab

Tags: angularjs, layout, tabs, ag-grid

I've used ag-grid, and have followed the rule of having the parent div of the page define an explicit height so that I can set a maximum height on the grid, allowing scrolling, rather than growing in heigh indefinitely. So, I have something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl" style="box-sizing: border-box; padding-top: 5px; width: 100%; height: 90%">

...
   <div ag-grid="myGridOptions" class="ag-blue" style="width: 100%; height: 55%"></div>
```

This works fine, and the percentage behave as you'd expect.

I'd now like to set up some tabs using the angular material md-tabs. When I put my ag-grid inside the tabs, it seems that the height value I've set isn't high enough. I assume that it's using the height of the md-tab or the md-tabs, however, I'm not sure how/if I can explicitly set the height of the tab. I've tried doing so with a 'style' attribute, but it seems to have no effect.

I assume I need to force the tab, or tab container to be a certain height, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
<div ng-cloak>
    <md-tabs md-border-bottom >
        <md-tab label="Tab1" >
            <div ag-grid="myGrid2Options" class="ag-blue" style="width: 100%; height: 70%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try add `md-dynamic-height` at `<md-tabs>`

Documentation: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs

```
<div ng-cloak>
<md-tabs md-border-bottom md-dynamic-height >
    <md-tab label="Tab1" >
        <div ag-grid="myGrid2Options" class="ag-blue" style="width: 100%; height: 70%;"></div>
```

Comment: Setting `md-dynamic-height` has an effect, but the grid can't have a fixed height %, and instead grows as high as it needs to be, and then the md-tabs also grows in height. It doesn't allow me to have the grid be a fixed % height with scrolling.

Comment: What does seem to work is if I set md-dynamic-height  on the md-tabs, and then set the ag-grid height to be a fixed height in px, rather than a %. I'll mark this as correct, since using md-dynamic-height got me to the solution, but am curious if you had other suggestions

Comment: Yon can try flexboxes, or `vh` instead of `px`. But the more flexible way is write something like `setHeight` directive, where you will calculate height for your mdtab content